# why the execute sql script is not working in kettle

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using kettle to get data from one table (t1) and joining execute sql script tool (t2) and then making an insert/update in the same table (t1)

Here's my transform

**table input tool**

```
select stud_id,mark from student;
```

**execute sql Script**

```
select s.stud_id,ifnull(m.mark,0) as mark from mark as m inner join student as s on (s.stud_id=m.stud_id) where s.student_id='?'
```

*fields*: stud_id

**insert/update tool**

- *table*: student
- *check*: stud_id=stud_id
- *update*: mark=mark

When I run this, it's successfully running but the values are not inserted or updated in target table.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Execute SQL Script` step is the one I think your referring to, it doesn't generate output. It's for forming up a bunch of SQL statements in your transform and running them individually. I'm not in front of PDI right now, but I believe the way to run a dynamic SQL statement and add its output to your data flow is the `Execute Dynamic SQL` step.

Never the less, in your case I would use a `Database Join` step instead. This step prepares the statement and just re-executes the query plan for each row that arrives in the transform, substituting data into parameter markers. Much more performance friendly.

Comment: Hi,Yes if i use database join its works but i need data from same database,not from different database so why i have to use database join ?,normally datbase join will reduce the performance right.

Comment: If that's the case, why would you need an `Execute SQL Script` step? You should be able to push it down to the SQL in the `Table Input` step. And the `Database Join` step does not always reduce performance. It depends on what you're trying to do with it, but if you know you can only ever get 1 row back, the `Database Lookup` step would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The Execute SQL step is for INSERTS, DELETES, UPDATES, CREATES, etc.

For a SELECT query, you would use Table Input.